# can I use time limit based cache using firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

sorry for my bad Engish. I know that there is cache method that I can use in `.get(source)` , if I use `Source.Default` then it will automatically get data from cahce if there is no internet connection.

but what I really want is something like this.

say there is a search bar, when a user search using the same keyword in the last 5 minutes,  then just get data from cache (because the data is relatively the same), otherwise fetch data from server. is there a method provided by firestore to do that ? something like Retrofit cache in Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore APIs don't offer anything like this.  You will need to write code to keep track of time yourself, and change the source of the query based on your condition.